# WP - External links not working on iPhones

Tags: css, iphone, wordpress, genesis, external-links

I'm trying to help out a friend but haven't had much luck so far. She had a website for an event developed but only just noticed that all external links don't work on iPhones. I've been hoping to google the issue but haven't had any luck so far :/

They built the website on WP/Genesis theme. It's just a one-page site with a few external links in hover boxes. As in, there are pictures, you hover over them and then there are external links coming up that you can click on. They work fine on all sizes on my desktop computer and on android phones. The links show up as text only on iPhones (as in, the ahref appears to be missing).

Does anyone have any thoughts on this and could please push me in the right direction? I haven't got much experience with WordPress and am not sure if I need to install a plugin for this or if there's somewhere where I could just add all those hrefs manually?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you have [this](http://www.zdnet.com/article/ios-9-3-heres-whats-breaking-hyperlinks-for-iphone-and-ipad-users/) problem...

Comment: Thanks a lot, definitely haven't come across this one in my research so far!